# Activar un checkbox cuando se desactiva otro?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Tengo el siguiente checkbox:

```
<label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SeleccionTipos[i].Selected, new { @class = "chk", id = "Tipos" })&nbsp;@Model.SeleccionTipos[i].Text</label>
```

Estoy usando el siguiente script:

```
$('input.chk').on('change', function () {
$('input.chk').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Hardcodeado del Modelo ya dejo seleccionado el primer checkbox. 
En este caso, solo tengo dos checkbox y cuando el usuario selecciona la segunda opcion la primera se descheckea y viceversa.

El problema es cuando descheckea una opcion, ambas pueden quedar en blanco lo cual no debería.

Este script usa on change, es posible agregar un "or on uncheck?" .
Otra manera seria utilizando un for y validar la cantidad de unchecked supongo.

Comment: ¿Por qué no utilizas botones de radio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si cambia a true, pasar los otros a false, si cambia a false y no queda ninguno dejarlo en true.

```js
$('input.chk').on('change', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault()
  // a que cambia?
  console.log(ev.target.checked, $(this).prop('checked'))
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $('input.chk').not($(this)).prop('checked', false)
  }
  // cuantos quedan?
  console.log($('input.chk:checked').length)

  if (1 > $('input.chk:checked').length) {
    $(this).prop('checked', true)
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id=o1 type=checkbox class=chk value=1 checked=checked name=opciones />
<label for=o1>opción 1</label>
<input id=o2 type=checkbox class=chk value=2 name=opciones />
<label for=o2>opción 2</label>
<input id=o3 type=checkbox class=chk value=3 name=opciones />
<label for=o3>opción 3</label>
```

Alternativamente podes usar radio buttons que parezcan checkboxes ( el svg es de ejemplo podes buscar alguno mas acorde a tu UI ):

```css
svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container-opciones input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox],
input[type=radio] {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  line-height: normal;
}

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.container-opciones input[type=radio]+label {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container-opciones label span {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
.container-opciones input[type=radio]:checked+label .icon-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.container-opciones input[type=radio]+label .icon-checkbox {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
}

.container-opciones input[type=radio]:checked+label .icon-checkbox-checked {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
.container-opciones input[type=radio]+label .icon-checkbox-checked {
    display: none;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<svg display="none">
  <symbol id="checkbox" viewBox="0 0 28 28">
    <path d="M0 0v28h28V0H0zm24 24H4V4h20v20z"/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="checkbox-checked" viewBox="0 0 28 28">
    <path d="M0 0v28h28V0H0zm24 24H4V4h20v20zm-2-13l-2.828-2.828-6.768 6.982-3.576-3.576L6 14.406l6.404 6.406L22 11z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
<div class=container-opciones>
  <input id=o1 type=radio name=opciones checked=checked value=1/>
  <label for=o1><span></span>
    <svg class="icon-checkbox">
      <use xlink:href="#checkbox"></use>
    </svg>
    <svg class="icon-checkbox-checked">
      <use xlink:href="#checkbox-checked"></use>
    </svg>
    opción 1
  </label>
  <input id=o2 type=radio name=opciones value=2/>
  <label for=o2><span></span>
    <svg class="icon-checkbox">
      <use xlink:href="#checkbox"></use>
    </svg>
    <svg class="icon-checkbox-checked">
      <use xlink:href="#checkbox-checked"></use>
    </svg>
    opción 2
  </label>
  <input id=o3 type=radio name=opciones value=3/>
  <label for=o3><span></span>
    <svg class="icon-checkbox">
      <use xlink:href="#checkbox"></use>
    </svg>
    <svg class="icon-checkbox-checked">
      <use xlink:href="#checkbox-checked"></use>
    </svg>
    opción 3
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias alo Malbarez!